# Locals used in output?

Tags: terraform, output, local-variables

I have a network module that creates a VPC, subnets, route tables, igw, nat etc.

To output all relevant information to the caller, I have a local variable that looks like this:

```
output_rtables = {
  for rtable in aws_route_table.rtable : rtable.id => {
    id                      = rtable.id
    name                    = rtable.tags["Name"]
    vpc                     = rtable.vpc_id
    routes                  = flatten([
      for rtable in rtable.route : {
        for key, value in rtable : key => value if value != ""
      }
    ])
  }
}
```

I then use that in an output:

```
output "rtable" {
    value = local.output_rtables
}
```

On the first `apply`, the `routes` value is `[]`:

```
  "rtb-route_table_id" = {
    "id" = "rtb-route_table_id"
    "name" = "my_route_table_name"
    "routes" = []
    "vpc" = "vpc-vpc_id"
  }
```

However, running `apply` again, it is now being populated correctly!

```
  "rtb-route_table_id" = {
    "id" = "rtb-route_table_id"
    "name" = "my_route_table_name"
    "routes" = [
      {
        "cidr_block" = "0.0.0.0/0"
        "nat_gateway_id" = "nat-nat_gateway_id"
      },
    ]
    "vpc" = "vpc-vpc_id"
  }
```

Not sure if I'm doing this correctly, or if this is a bug?

Comment: Ok, more thinking about this and I THINK I know what's going on.

TF sees that the local depends on the `aws_route_table.rtable` (which is done in a `for_each = { ... }` and just after all of them are create, "creates" the local.

BUT it needs to wait for ALL of it being done (especially all the separate `aws_route` resources have been created before "creating" the local.

But I know of no way to do a `depends_on` in a `local`!

Comment: Why do you even need the local?

Comment: Doesn't matter if I put that part directly in the output..

Comment: Indeed the `local` is superfluous. Removing it would likely fix the issue and improve the code.

Comment: As I said, I tried putting it in the output directly, but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to the routes in is way then you will need to declare them inline inside the `aws_route_table` resource configuration, rather than using separate `aws_route` resources. Otherwise the routes are not actually part of the route table as far as Terraform is concerned; it only "works" on the second apply due to a design quirk of the AWS provider where it can't distinguish between separate route declarations and "drift" of the `route` blocks inside the `aws_route_table` resource.

If declaring the routes inside `aws_route_table` is not appropriate for your overall design then you'll need to instead collect the routes up from the various `aws_route` resources and use *those* to build your `routes` list in our output value. Your question doesn't include the routes themselves so I can't show a concrete example, but it will presumably consist of references to each of your `aws_route` resources taking the relevant attributes of each.